# Flex3: How Do I Add a Twitter Share Button?

Tags: apache-flex, twitter

I've got a Flex 3 website. How do I add a Twitter share button?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: I have to wonder why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial, which shows how to do it: [link](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/blogs/52/Facebook-and-Twitter-buttons-in-Flash-and-Flex.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regular Flex Button that links to twitter.  Conceptually something like this:

```
<mx:Button id="TwitterButton" click="onClick()" />
```

The onClick method should just create a new URLRequest and the navigate to it.

```
<mx:script>
 public function onClick():void{
   var urlRequest = new URLRquest('/http://twitter.com/share?url=http://bit.ly/fKYLIN&text=I just got a free Flex AutoComplete Component courtesy of @Flextras It rocks! Be sure to get your own');
   navigateToURL(urlRequest);
 }
</mx:script>
```

The twitter URL format should be documented somewhere in the twitter help.  [Start here](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton) and [then go here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button).

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Laxmidi IF you feel this answer completely answers your questions; be sure to mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should factually use the Twitter AS3 API.
Sharing on twitter is just a function call away, if you use that API.
You can get the details here

- http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/twitter_widget/
- http://johannesluderschmidt.de/lang/en-us/twitter-as3-library-twitterscript-flex-example/564/
- http://code.google.com/p/tweetr/